# Where can I find JMock Blitzer?

Tags: java, testing, concurrency, jmock

I see it described at http://www.jmock.org/threading-blitzer.html but I don't see it in the 2.5.1 jar files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right [here](http://www.jmock.org/download.html)?

---

link posted above is dead, updated [git link](https://github.com/jmock-developers/jmock-library)

Comment: Been there.  Which jar file is it in?  Note that the 2.5.1 Javadoc doesn't mention it, either.

Comment: Ah, it looks like it's new in 2.6.0-RC2.